# Public RDF Ontology for Football (soccer) or Tennis?

Tags: rdf, owl, ontology, protege, turtle-rdf

Do you know of an RDF ontology for either football or tennis matches? I want to describe play-by-play events in the game and some statistics datasets.

I did an extenstive reaserch but only really found the generic BBC Ontology for sports as a whole.

Comment: This question, as it asks for a resource recommendation, is off-topic on Stack Overflow. I think this question would be on-topic on https://opendata.stackexchange.com/ – but it would be good to include in your question what kind of data you want to describe about the matches.

Answer (score 0):

There is [`dbo:FootballMatch`](https://dbpedia.org/ontology/FootballMatch), or [`dbo:SportsEvent`](https://dbpedia.org/ontology/SportsEvent) in general, and also [`dbo:SoccerTournament`](https://dbpedia.org/ontology/SoccerTournament) and [`dbo:TennisTournament`](https://dbpedia.org/ontology/TennisTournament). There is no `dbo:SoccerMatch` or `dbo:TennisMatch`, but you can link individual matches to tournaments they were part of, or to the particular sports (such as [`dbr:Tennis`](https://dbpedia.org/page/Tennis)). You may use other general-purpose properties for the links, or other statistics.